# SignalR and client certificate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr.client

I plan to use SignalR to notify clients.

In production we are forced to use a client x509 certificate to authenticate the client using a reverse proxy. It will also terminate the SSL prior to connecting to our IIS webserver.

Will this work?

I can't find any api to add the client certificate or to use a WebRequestHandler.

I can't be the first.

/HAXEN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go, with version 1.1 of SignalR Client Certificates are supported out of the box.

Great!

Answer (score 2):

Regarding using client-based certificate: there is nothing in SingalR that allows to do it, I went through all the sources, and apparently it's an oversight, and a very annoying one. Here's a hack that I found:

```
    public class MyHttpClient: IHttpClient
    {
        DefaultHttpClient _client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        X509Certificate Certificate;

        Action<IRequest> SpiceAction(Action<IRequest> prepareRequest)
        {
            return new Action<IRequest>(req =>
            {
                var fi = typeof(HttpWebRequestWrapper).GetField("_request",
                     BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) fi.GetValue(req);
                request.ClientCertificates.Add(Certificate);
                prepareRequest(req);
            });
        }

        public Task<IResponse> Get(string url, Action<IRequest> prepareRequest)
        {
            return _client.Get(url, SpiceAction(prepareRequest));
        }

        public Task<IResponse> Post(string url, Action<IRequest> prepareRequest,
            IDictionary<string, string> postData)
        {
            return _client.Post(url, SpiceAction(prepareRequest), postData);
        }
    }
```

and then instead of:

```
    var conn = new Connection("https://xxxxxxxx");
    conn.Start()
```

do:

```
    var conn = new Connection("https://xxxxxxxx");
    conn.Start(new MyHttpClient() { Certificate = xxxxxxx });
```

Comment: Yea, this is the same solution that we came up with. Still surprised it's not included.